# Unique/conditional count formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to calculate if there was an upgrade for a supplier, not the total count.

So, for each contract, for each supplier, was there an upgrade (regardless of the count/sum of upgrades)? If the result is yes, then the answer is 1.

[image]

In the example above the count of the upgrades is 9, but the answer I am looking to generate is 4.

I am guessing to calculate this I would need a combination of IF, AND, COUNTIF, MAX, but I can't seem to put it together.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: So, to understand your question, you're saying the number is 4 because you have 4 suppliers (Souther, Reece, Love, Selk) and each of them had at least one row where upgrade qnty wasn't blank?

Comment: Answer should be 3. How it is 4 as `Selk` has no upgrade? Can you explain.

Comment: @JohnBustos the answer is 4 as there are five suppliers (including Reece twice) across the two different contracts. What I'm looking to count is the total number of rows for each supplier, within each contract, if any row of a supplier in the upgrade quantity column is >0. Selk is 0 as there is no upgrade at all.

Comment: @Harun24HR see my answer above. Apologies as this is difficult to explain!

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula-

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B15&A2:A15,D2:D15>0))<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: I think we're close now! Hopefully this helps more. Column F is the formula calculation with the result, G is the formula text. I just need to add one more condition to this formula, as it currently does not account for the fact that Selk has no upgrades in row 15 or 16, so I need something that will return a result of 0 in F15 and F16.

Comment: @Scott From your data it is hard for excel to detect which one is upgrade or not. Any logic to detect why it would be considered as not upgrade?

Comment: sorry no, the only logic is if all the rows for a supplier, within a contract, are blank, then that would not be an upgrade. If at least one row for a supplier within a contract has an upgrade quantity, then it is considered an upgrade

Comment: @Scott Then you could try `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,D:D,">0")`.

Answer (score 1):

Below formula should works. [Reference here](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-with-criteria)

```
=IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B15, D2:D15>0))), 0)
```

Comment: It will return `3`.

Comment: @Harun24HR Thanks for pointing out! I didn’t see the updated requirements - instead of “D2:D15<>””” it should be “D2:D15>0”

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=SUM((D2:D15>0)*(IFERROR(1/COUNTIFS(A2:A15,A2:A15,B2:B15,B2:B15,D2:D15,">0"),0)))
```

This is an CS-entered array formula if you are not working through MS365.